# Retorno de Promesas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promesas

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Me podrian decir el error que estoy cometiendo, en este fragmento de codigo (react)
o dar alguna recomendacion...

```
  const getModelo= async ()=>{
        return await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/tipoProducto/listaModelo/1`)   
    }

 console.log(getModelo())
```

Quisiera que me retorne un array.
gracias de antemano

Psd: Solo me retorna una promesa. ya probe "async" y "then" ....

Comment: Y el problema es..?

Comment: el problema es q solo me devuelve una promesa.... ya edite mi pregunta gracias :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas llamando al `console.log(getModelo())` fuera de tu función asíncrona.

Por lo que se solucionaría así

```
const getModelo = async () => {
   const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/tipoProducto/listaModelo/1`)
   console.log(response)
}
```

Ahora, si necesitas llamar a *getModelo* en otra parte, esta llamada también debe estar dentro de una función asíncrona.

```
const otraFuncion = async () => {
   const res = await getModelo()
   // más código
}
```

Nos comentas si te funcionó!

Comment: Excelente! si ya me salio.... tenia razon con la forma de llamar a la function asincrona , Gracias :3